# Multiple amp-image overlays. How to properly do this in wordpress?

Tags: images, css, block-editor, mobile, responsive

## Summary

### Goal

I want to:

1. Add multiple overlays to an image, on a page, created with gutenberg, rendered as amp-img on the frontend. I want [this](https://jsbin.com/qadidaxeze/edit?html,css,output) kind of end result, but added through gutenberg.
2. When tapped on mobile (I realize I'm going to need to add amp-events for this), or hovered on desktop, I want to display a content-div, preferably on top of the image, in the bottom left corner. [Iv'e accomplished about half of this](https://jsbin.com/qadidaxeze/edit?html,css,output), but I still can't get the info div to display when hovering the corresponding overlay.
3. *Make sure the overlay-divs are correctly positioned and shaped on different screen sizes since I'm using a responsive design.* **Seems like I've managed to do this myself already.**

### Expected vs actual results

#### Expected

Thought I was going to be able to simply add a custom html block in gutenberg, with a "hacked" amp-img tag containing the hmtl part in [the jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qadidaxeze/edit?html,css,output).

#### Actual

I'm completely unable to control (input any element within the amp-img) the output of the amp-img tag. When I try to add the amp-img tags manually, it gets removed from the page on the front-end, due to amp-errors.

### Errors

If I try to add the amp-img tag manually, using a custom html block in gutenberg, The content gets removed due to amp-errors.

## What I've tried

Well you can [see the jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qadidaxeze/edit?html,css,output) for a general conclusion on the current state of affairs. Next, I'll try to disable the amp-error that stops the custom html from rendering. If that doesn't work, I think I'm going to have to change strategy altogether. Possibly creating a page-pagename.php template, and entering the content from the jsbin directly through there.

## Code

[See this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/qadidaxeze/edit?html,css,output)

## Conclusion / The questions

Adding an amp-img with content inside the tag - Is this simply something that's not *supposed* to be done? 
Can it be done from gutenberg, and if so, can it be done using any kind of good practice?